# How can I install ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server on Travis CI?

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up continuous integration on a private github repo using Travis CI to maintain an R package. There are unit tests that connect to SQL so I need to install the `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server`. I've tried a few approaches from around the web, to no avail. The issue that I get is that at some point Travis tries to call an ODBC server, which returns:

`[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`

So here go some solutions I've tried to no avial:

```
  - wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/5/2E58F097-805C-4AB8-9FC6-71288AB4409D/msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz -P ..
  - tar xvzf ../msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz -C ..
  - sed -i '14d' ../msodbcsql-13.0.0.0/build_dm.sh
  - sed -i '/tmp=/ctmp=/tmp/odbcbuilds'  ../msodbcsql-13.0.0.0/build_dm.sh  
  - ../msodbcsql-13.0.0.0/build_dm.sh --accept-warning
```

gives:

```
[0K$ wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/5/2E58F097-805C-4AB8-9FC6-71288AB4409D/msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz -P ..
--2019-03-14 16:28:05--  https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/5/2E58F097-805C-4AB8-9FC6-71288AB4409D/msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz
Resolving download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)... 23.35.205.15, 2600:1404:27:783::e59, 2600:1404:27:78d::e59
Connecting to download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)|23.35.205.15|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

fair enough... the link is broken. Next approach:

```
 - sudo su
 -  sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/mssql-ubuntu-xenial-release/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlpreview.list'
 - sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
```

^ can't claim sudo like that, and obviously w/out the sudo stuff nothing works. Next approach:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libudunits2-dev

script:
  - docker run --net=host -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd' -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
  - echo "Running docker for commit $TRAVIS_COMMIT"
```

This doesn't seem to work either. Also tried random docker versions:

```
- docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

At this point I'm basically trying anything I can get my hands on. Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:** Here is the result of Jan's Answer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands to install latest version:

```
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl add-apt-key apt-transport-https
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlrelease.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y msodbcsql mssql-tools
```

Installed `msodbcsql` packages after these commands:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep msodbcsql

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

msodbcsql/xenial,now 13.1.9.2-1 amd64 [installed]
msodbcsql17/xenial,now 17.3.1.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

If you need exact version 13.0.0.0, then you will need to customize installed package versions.

Comment: thanks Jan, unfortunately that didn't work... it seems like the second line failed... pls see the output in my original question EDIT at the end.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I did paste all the commands. the script failed as shown and didn't run through them all.